# How to write part of the app on azure?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Hi all hope this question is actually asked the right way

i have been researching for hours and i can't get anything that would help me achieve what i want...

Here's the thing i am currently developing a windows phone app that uses cloud features (like sql azure,authentication,etc...) and what i had in mind is that i want to divide the code into two parts:

the first on the cloud where it handles all the operations and logic that makes use of the cloud and take different parameters as input

the second part on the phone which is basically the interface and any local operations

i want this so that in the future i can write ios and android versions of the app with minimum code

also if any of you would please provide some links to a beginner level mobile azure programmer i would be very very grateful since all the tutorials seem to assume previous experience or are outdated....i used azure before but never as a mobile developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Mobile services as backend for your apps and in front, you can use Ionic / Cordova / Phonegap to build views using HTML5 / CSS3 and compile to IOS / Android / Windows Phone.

Please check channel9 links:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/windows+azure+mobile+services

https://cordova.apache.org/

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

http://tech.pro/blog/1704/2-ways-to-get-started-with-phonegapapache-cordova